# Does the carboxylate group show a positive or a negative inductive effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

In the benzoate ion, does the carboxylate group show a $-I$ or a $+I$ effect?

I learnt that the carboxylate group is a $-I$ group, but according to a website the carboxylate group in benzoate shows a $+I$ effect.

[image: M and I effects of benzoate]

So, which one is correct? Does the carboxylate group show a positive or a negative inductive effect?

Please neglect mesomeric effect when answering.

Comment: To the close voters, I think this question shows enough thought and reasoning not to close it. To the OP, please make sure to [edit] and cite your source.

Comment: the carboxylic acid group always shows -I effect due to the presence of electronegative oxygen atoms, however the carboxylate group(COO-) shows +I effect due to excess negative charge.

Answer (score 5):

The carboxy group is electron-withdrawing both by inductive and by mesomeric mechanisms. I have drawn two depictions in the scheme below. The upper one is how the mesomeric effect of the carboxy group can be explained. This effect is only relevant if the $\ce{COOH}$ fragment is in the same plane as the ring.

[image: depictions of the inductive and mesomeric effects of a carboxy group]

In the case of 2,6-di(*tert*-butyl)benzoic acid, the bulky *tert*-butyl groups prevent the mesomerism depicted above. The carboxy group is perpendicular to the ring. Yet, this group still exercises an electron-withdrawing inductive effect. It can be explained by a mesomeric structure of the $\ce{C=O}$ double bond with charge separation:

$$\ce{C=O <-> C^+-O^-}$$

This positive charge is, naturally, electron-withdrawing and can be used to explain the $-I$ effect of carboxy groups. No matter which mesomeric depiction you choose, you can **never** get a negative charge on the carboxy carbon, thus it will *always* remain partially positive. That also makes sense considering it is bonded to two electron-withdrawing, strongly electronegative oxygen atoms.

Comment: I believe he's asking about the carboxylate group not the carboxy group