# Why does the carboxylate ion show positive inductive effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

While solving some problems on general organic chemistry, I came across this question that asked for the nature of inductive effects of $\ce{-CH_3}, \ce{-CO_2^-}, \ce{-Br}, \ce{-NH_3^+}$.

And in the solution to that problem, it says $\ce{-CO_2^-}$ shows $\ce{+I}$ effect.

How is it possible that the carboxylate ion with its two electronegative oxygen atoms shows a positive inductive effect instead of attracting a negative charge towards itself?

Please provide clarification on this.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63181/does-the-carboxylate-group-show-a-positive-or-a-negative-inductive-effect?rq=1

Comment on this answer might be a answer to your question

Comment: Why would a negatively charged species attract a negative charge?