# Why is the lysine side chain more basic?

Tags: acid-base, amines, amino-acids, carboxylic-acids

As per [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/LYSINE#section=Dissociation-Constants): $pK_1 = 2.18$; $pK_2 = 8.95$; $pK_3 = 10.53$ at 38 °C, indicating that the side chain amino group is deprotonated at a higher pH, indicating it is more basic. I tried to justify this by analysing electronic effects in the conjugate acid: [image]

Attempt I) The carboxylic acid group, at a higher pH would exist as $\ce{-COO}^{-}$ and exert a +I effect on nearby atoms. Then the alpha-amino group should be more stable in the protonated form and be more basic.

Attempt II) The carboxylate anion and $\ce{-NH_3}^{+}$ group may form hydrogen bonds. This again leads me to conclude that the alpha-amino group should be more basic.

But the experimental data contradict this. Perhaps the carboxylate anion H-bonds with (and stabilises) the side-chain amino group instead, but this seems unlikely (9-membered ring?).

Could anyone provide a decent theoretical explanation of the $pKa$ values?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63181/does-the-carboxylate-group-show-a-positive-or-a-negative-inductive-effect#:~:text=the%20carboxylic%20acid%20group%20always,due%20to%20excess%20negative%20charge.

Comment: Do you have a source for COO- being a +I group?

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati Solomons/Fryhle/Snyder adapted by MS Chouhan, page 93

Comment: We must have different editions, my page 93(2016) is about Lewis acids and bases, btw all the best for your jee

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati It is a few sections after that in the 2019 edition. "Relationships between structure and acidity". And thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the alkyl groups provide a better stabilizing effect, i don't know about the strength of the induction of the carboxylate.

Comment: In aqueous solution, the solvation of the COO- group ensures that it maintains an I- effect. This is clearly observed in a comparison of the ammonium group pKa on glycine (~9.8) vs methylamine (~ 10.7). This effect is much stronger for the a-amino group of lysine vs the e-amino group, whose pKa is close to what is typical for an alkyl amine

Comment: @Andrew that is what I was suspecting, but why does the text mention COO- as a +I group? Is that with respect to vapour phase?

Comment: @Andrew seems plausible, if you can cite sources saying the same I can accept that explanation. Since some texts directly contradict that.